# When click on editText keyboard show and login button hide how to adjuct automatic button above the keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

Aleady added in manifest,

`:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

please suggest solution?
try with `NestedScrollView` but not working it it works but when i scroll screen through finger then button can show. Please give some suggestion to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

To hide the keyboard

```
   val insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)  // view can be edittext or root view

        insets?.let {
            val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window,view)

            // Show Keyboard if not visible
            if (!it.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())){
                insetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
            }
            
            // Hide Keyboard
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

        }
```